# I have a non-functional lambda. How I can run it locally in order to find out what's wrong?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I was tasked to debug an aws lambda written in python 2.7.x . But instead of uploading and executing it all over the time I need somehow to run it locally.

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES there's a way. In my case due to the lack of pip usage of my project I installed globally via (using Ubuntu GNU/Linux) the [`python-lambda-local`](https://pypi.org/project/python-lambda-local/) tool:

```
sudo -H pip install python-lambda-local
```

A better way is a local per-project installation and use a build system in order to build your lambda.

Then I used the following command sequence:

```
cd ^lambda_dir^
echo "{}" > events.json
```

Then I execute the handler function like:

```
python-lambda-local -l . -f ^handler_function^ -t 5 ^lambda_python_file^ events.json
```

In other words I went into my lambda source code, I created a `events.json` file that contains all the required parameters. Even if NO input parameters taken, like in my case, this file should exist. In case of input parameters populate it accordingly as seen in library's [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-lambda-local/).

Afterwards using the `python-lambda-local` executable installed via `pip`, and specifying the file `^lambda_python_file^` and the function to execute `^handler_function^` it should do the job.

The library directory is specified via the `-l` parameter.